# Declare and access 2D-vector initiated in constructor c++

Tags: c++, vector, 2d

I have a class declared in a header file, where I have the following 2D vector:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > inputPatterns;
```

Then in the constructor of this class in my .cpp file, I do the following:

```
nInputPatterns = 4;
vector< vector<int> > inputPatterns(nInputPatterns, vector<int>(2));

inputPatterns[0][0] = 1;
inputPatterns[0][1] = 1;
inputPatterns[1][0] = 0;
inputPatterns[1][1] = 1;
inputPatterns[2][0] = 1;
inputPatterns[2][1] = 0;
inputPatterns[3][0] = 0;
inputPatterns[3][1] = 0;
```

However, now member function of this class can't access this 2D vector. I think that it is because I redeclare it in the constructor, but I don't know how to do it otherwise.

So my question is, how to properly declare the 2D vector in the header class and then initialise it in the .cpp file (either in the constructor or a member function) such that I can access it everywhere?

Comment: Use `this->inputPatterns` and then initialize it / populate it.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to define it in constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem seems to be to use inputPatterns.assign(nInputPatterns, vector(2)); So not this->. Can anybody explain me why?

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring a new local variable, populating it, and then will die once the control goes out of the constructors scope. Therefore, you did not actually populate the member variable of the object, you populated an other variable that died by the time the constructor finished executing.

What you would need to do is to use the existing member variable of the class instead, and the best way for improving the code and make it more readable / understandable is to use the [**`this`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) pointer like here:

```
nInputPatterns = 4;

// means not any inputPatterns, it is explicitly the member variable inputPatterns of "this" current object / instance
this->inputPatterns(nInputPatterns, vector<int>(2)); 

// ..
```

Comment: Then I get the following error: MLP.cpp:13:1: error: type 'std::vector<std::vector<int> >' does not provide a
      call operator
this->inputPatterns(nInputPatterns, vector<int>(2));

Comment: Using .assign instead of this-> seems to have solved the issue. Do you have any clue why?